# How to make safe frequent DataSource switches for AbstractRoutingDataSource?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I implemented Dynamic DataSource Routing  for Spring+Hibernate according to [this article](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/). I have several databases with same structure and I need to select which db will run each specific query.

Everything works fine on localhost, but I am worrying about how this will hold up in real web site environment. They are using some static context holder to determine which datasource to use:

```
public class  CustomerContextHolder {

   private static final ThreadLocal<CustomerType> contextHolder =
            new ThreadLocal<CustomerType>();

   public static void setCustomerType(CustomerType customerType) {
      Assert.notNull(customerType, "customerType cannot be null");
      contextHolder.set(customerType);
   }

   public static CustomerType getCustomerType() {
      return (CustomerType) contextHolder.get();
   }

   public static void clearCustomerType() {
      contextHolder.remove();
   }
}
```

It is wrapped inside some ThreadLocal container, but what exactly does that mean? What will happen when two web requests call this piece of code in parallel:

```
CustomerContextHolder.setCustomerType(CustomerType.GOLD);
//<another user will switch customer type here to CustomerType.SILVER in another request>
List<Item> goldItems = catalog.getItems();
```

Is every web request wrapped into its own thread in Spring MVC? Will `CustomerContextHolder.setCustomerType()` changes be visible to other web users? My controllers have `synchronizeOnSession=true`.

How to make sure that nobody else will switch datasource until I run required query for current user?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll be fine. Each Servlet request executes in a single thread (and Spring is just Servlets underneath).

Have you considered using Hibernate Shards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is every web request wrapped into its own thread in Spring MVC?

Yes, but this has nothing to do with Spring MVC, the container is doing that (the container has a thread pool and picks one of the them to handle each request).

> Will CustomerContextHolder.setCustomerType() changes be visible to other web users?

No. A [`ThreadLocal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) is by definition local to a thread. From the javadoc:

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its `get` or `set` method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable. `ThreadLocal` instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

What you `set` in a `ThreadLocal` is not visible to other threads. You should be fine